# Run python script in terminal

Tags: python, shell, terminal

I have created this python script called 'SleepCalc.py'. It is a simple script that tells me when to wake up based on 90 minute sleep cycles. Usually I open terminal, cd command my way to the dir containing the .py and then execute the script with the 'python' command.

What I want to know is how can I make an app/automator workflow/apple script that I can double click and it executes the python script in the terminal without me having to cd, etc.

http://codebin.org/view/98c0b7c5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add shebang: `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top of your script.

And then give the file permission to execute by:

```
chmod +x SleepCalc.py
```

Comment: Then how do I 'run' it? I double click it and it opens in Xcode. I try to open with > terminal but terminal isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

You open Terminal and enter `nano` at the top. It opens up a Terminal-based text editor.

After that, type `python` followed by the file path (at the beginning, include `~/` because the computer starts at the root).

Do `Control-X`, click `Yes`, and save it as `launch.command`.

After that, type `chmod +x` and drag the newly created file into the Terminal window. This gives permission for the file to execute.

From then on, you can double click the `.command` file to launch `SleepCalc.py`.